# What is the SIMPLEST way to send file input via AJAX & PHPMailer?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, phpmailer

I'm trying to send a file input on my form via AJAX and PHPMailer however, readying absolutely everything online and trying examples I'm not sure what the best method is.. Surely this can be done in a few lines of code? I can't find a good enough guide / demo anywhere online or on the stackoverflow site to go through

Would be GREAT if someone could show a way for multiple file uploads from one input field too?

File input:

`<input type="file" name="attachments" id="attachments"/>`

JS Formdata:

`attachments : $('#attachments').prop('files')`

AJAX Post:

`$.ajax({ type: "POST", url: 'sendmail.php', data: form_data, async: true, success: function(value) { }, error: function(value) { } });`

PHP Side?

`$attachments                                  = $_FILES['attachments'];`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file#multiple

Comment: It's the AJAX / PHP Side I'm getting stuck on

Comment: using  Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

Mail::send('example_mail_view_php_file_path',
            function ($message) use ($email, $attachment) {
                    $message->to($email)
                        ->subject('Your subject')
                        ->attachData(
                            $attachment, 'attachment_name', [
                                'mime' => 'attchment_type (application/pdf)'
                            ]
                        );
                }
            });

Comment: Well you've been shown the necessary AJAX code (in the duplicate in the blue box). You also asked how to allow multiple files to be selected, so I've shown you about the `multiple` attribute in HTML, which is what you need. As for the PHP side, you need to be clearer about what exactly the problem is. Make sure the AJAX is working and actually sending files first, and then you can start to see if there are any problems in the PHP.